# Jquery SelectBox Plugin already has errors

Tags: jquery, plugins, drop-down-menu

I am currently working on a web application and am kind of learning things as I go. I've never used Jquery before but I'm doing my research as I am making the app. I've made a simple web application and it has a drop down select box, and now I'm trying to make it look pretty. So I've decided to download the jquery select box plugin. However, there aren't many directions on how to use it anywhere, so I'm kind of just winging it. I downloaded the files and imported them into my project. The download I have came with three files:

jquery-1.7.2.min.js

jquery.selectbox-0.2.js

jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js

which look fine except for the last one. Literally all I did was import them and the third file is giving me errors. This is what the third file looks like. It is VERY long so i'll just post a small snippet:

```
(function(a,b){function cy(a){return f.isWindow(a)?a:a.nodeType===9?a.defaultView||a.parentWindow:!1}
function cu(a){if(!cj[a]){var b=c.body,d=f("<"+a+">").appendTo(b),e=d.css("display");d.remove();if(e==="none"||e==="")
{ck||(ck=c.createElement("iframe"),ck.frameBorder=ck.width=ck.height=0),b.appendChild(ck);if(!cl||!ck.createElement)cl=(ck.contentWindow||ck.contentDocument).document,cl.write((f.support.boxModel?"<!doctype html>":"")+"<html>
<body>"),cl.close();d=cl.createElement(a),cl.body.appendChild(d),e=f.css(d,"display"),b.removeChild(ck)}cj[a]=e}return cj[a]}function ct(a,b){var c={};f.each(cp.concat.apply([],c
```

and this is normally all on one line but i divvied it up so it is easier to read. 
The errors that I'm getting are:
Missing semicolon (this error is everywhere all over the document)
and "Syntax Error on 'Invalid Regular Expression Options' no accurate correction available" for this little section:

> contents:{xml:/xml/,html:/html/,json:/json/}

So I'm wondering if what I downloaded is wrong? Or maybe I was never supposed to import this file in the first place?

Did anyone else get this error before even altering anything? All I did was import.

Thank you.

Comment: The jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js file is simply a "minimized" file of the jquery.selectbox-0.2.js and would be used in a "production" environment as it's file size would be smaller. You typically would use the non minimized version for development, and then the minimized version for a production environment.

Comment: Both files contain the exact same content, just one is easier to read, I am still reading the rest of your question, and hopefully I might be able to help.

Comment: What does your header tag look like ? Are you referencing jquery-1.7.2.min.js, followed by jquery.selectbox-0.2.js? I think if you could provide more code, that would hopefully shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Well the code is so long for this file it actually exceeds the limit of characters I'm allowed to have. But if I don't need the minimized file I could just delete it... The other file isn't giving me any errors. I don't know why this is the case. And there is no header tag in the js file... I haven't even referenced the selectbox in my jsp file yet.

Comment: Yeah there should be no header in the js file, I was referring to the html header.

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gz8RR/)

Above is a working demo hopefully getting you started on what you need to do. Let me know if you need any more help.

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.selectbox/0.2/css/jquery.selectbox.css">
   <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.selectbox/0.2/js/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is the order in which you should reference the stylesheets and javascript.